# ZendFramework: Where's the best place to put Validation and Filter Rules

Tags: validation, filter

I want to validate and filter values before saving, like, converting to uppercase, remove spaces, remove accents, verify if valid email address, etc.

The ideas:

1. **Use Zend_Form**: I don't like this idea because the only way to validate and filter is in the form, but if values come from another place, like a WebService or internal procedure the validate and filter will not be applicable.
2. **Use The Validate in Controller**: This is a solution. Validate and Filter the Array of Params before pass to Model.
3. **Use The Validate in Model**: This is another solution.

What do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

Personnally, I created a class to process the forms. So I call it within the controller like this :

```
$request     = $this->getRequest();
$fp          = new FormProcessor($this->db);

if ($request->isPost()) 
                $fp->process($request);
```

the process method will do the job like this :

```
public function process(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
{       
       $this->title = $request->getPost('title');
}
```

Hope that's will help you.

Comment: But the question is: Where is the validate and filter methods ? As I said i need to treat this before to save. In fact, i need to centralize the treats.

Comment: I do all validations and filters within the process method.

Comment: Sorry but i'm not understading how do you use this method process. I'm new in ZendFramework.

Comment: Create the FormProcessor class just to centralize the treats with all methods you need. for exemple isValidEmail(), sanitize(), etc. then call them within the controller.

Comment: Ok, but do you use the Zend_Form for get the values ?

Comment: within the controller I pass the request object as an argument then I use getPost() or getQuery() methods on it to get the values.